# How to align all ajax validation error messages at the bottom of text box?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$("#taskDoneForm").validate({
    rules: {
        taskName : "required",
        loginType : "required",
        startDate : "required",
        endDate : "required",
        taskDescription : "required",
        taskLocation : "required",
        startTime : "required",
        endTime : "required"


    },
     messages: {
         startTime:{
             required: "time required"
         },
         endTime:{
             required: "time required"
         },
         taskName:{
             required: "task name required"
         },
         loginType:{
             required: "login type name required"
         },
         startDate:{
             required: "date required"
         },
         endDate:{
             required: "date required"
         },
         taskLocation:{
             required: "task location required"
         },
          taskDescription:{
             required: "task description required"
         },
          userOrGroup:{
             required: "select user/group"
         },
     },});
```

here i am validating a form named as taskDoneForm using this code ,but all the  validation messages are not shown at the bottom of text box.anyone please give solution to solve this  issue.thanks in advance

Comment: *not shown at the bottom* okay . now where it's showing ?

Comment: state the name of the plugin you are using

Comment: some error messages are shown at right side of textbox@JYoThI

Comment: jQuery Validation Plugin v1.15.0@kapreski

Comment: I think we need jsFiddle here to help you @ASWATHY